# Como criar sessão num servidor PHP para login feito numa aplicação separada (HTML + JS) usando Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session

Estou fazendo um hybrid app com o Phonegap (usando apenas HTML5, CSS e JS - jQuery e JQuery Mobile). Pra isso, tenho a aplicação em si, que não pode usar PHP, e um servidor à parte que cuida de coisas como o login. Há também um banco de dados.

Basicamente, uso solicitações Ajax que são recebidas pelo servidor, retornando os valores do banco de dados por JSON para que eles sejam exibidos na página. O login também funciona de forma parecida: os valores digitados nos inputs são enviados para um arquivo PHP no servidor, que valida o usuário e a senha e da uma resposta para a aplicação.

```
function Authenticate(username, password) {

    $.ajax({

            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost/app/login.php',
            data: { action: 'auth', username: username, password: password },

            success: function(data){

                if(data.result == 'true') {

                    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#events', {

                        transition: 'none',
                        changeHash: false,
                        reverse: false,
                        showLoadMsg: true

                    });

                }

                else {                      

                    $('#login-error').show();
                    $('#login-error').html('Usuário ou senha incorreta.');
                    $('#login-password').addClass('error');

                }


            },

            error: function() {

                alert('Erro Ajax');

            }

    });

}
```

E o arquivo PHP que recebe os dados:

```
case 'auth':

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        $stmt->execute();   

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $res = 'true';

        }

        else {

            $res = 'false';

        }

        echo json_encode(array("result" => $res));

        break;
```

Como um sistema bem básico, o usuário é redirecionado para a página #events (como funciona o JQuery Mobile) se a resposta do servidor for "true" ao procurar uma entrada no banco de dados com aquele usuário e aquela senha específica.

Pesquisando sobre sessões, vi que elas precisam ser sempre criadas e gerenciadas do lado do servidor, mas não consegui pensar em nenhuma forma de fazer isso no meu caso.

Como posso criar uma sessão para o usuário no lado do servidor quando este fizer login e acessar as variáveis da sessão na aplicação com Javascript para, por exemplo, redirecioná-lo diretamente da página #login para a página #events, se já houver uma sessão válida, ou, da mesma forma, redirecioná-lo da página #events para a página #login, se não houver uma sessão válida e o usuário não estiver logado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito seria seu `PHP` devolver o id da sessão para a aplicação, na aplicação armazenar este id para usar nas próximas requisições.

Exemplo `PHP`:

```
case 'auth':

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();   

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {

        session_start();
        $res = 'true';

    }

    else {

        $res = 'false';

    }

    echo json_encode(array("result" => $res, "sessid" => session_id()));

    break;
```

Neste exemplo sua aplicação ficaria encarregada de guardar o id de sessão e utilizá-lo nas próximas requisições a páginas que necessitam de sessões.

A seguir um exemplo (bem básico) de como recuperar este id e iniciar sessão com ele (resgatando assim as informações desta sessão):

```
 if( isset($_POST['sess_id']) ){
     session_id($_POST['sess_id']);
     session_start();
 }else {
    /**
     caso não tenha sido enviado um post contendo um id de sessão
     redirecionar para ua página de erro!
     */
 }
```

Para evitar acesso não autorizado basta criar um item em sua sessão quando fizeres a autenticação do cliente exemplo:

```
<?php
   // logo após iniciar a sessão
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['CLIENT-AUTH'] = 'true';
   $res = 'true';
```

E quando receber um "id" de sessão verificar se aquela sessão possui tal item:

```
 if( isset($_POST['sess_id']) ){
     session_id($_POST['sess_id']);
     session_start();

     // verficar se não existe um item
     if(!isset($_SESSION['CLIENT-AUTH']) AND $_SESSION['CLIENT-AUTH'] != 'true'){
        // destruir a sessão e redirecionar
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: página-de-erro.php');
        exit();

        // caso $_SESSION['CLIENT-AUTH'] exista o código corre normalmente
     }
 }else {
    /**
     caso não tenha sido enviado um post contendo um id de sessão
     redirecionar para uma página de erro!
     */
 }
```

Embora usar ids remotos para criar|recuperar dados de sessão não seja o recomendável funciona de boa, caso queira dar mais segurança recomendo dar uma olhada em [PHP Secure Session](https://github.com/ezimuel/PHP-Secure-Session) é um handler para criptografar dados de sessão.

Embora fora do escopo da pergunta uma maneira mais facil de recuperar dados de sessão seria armazená-los (a sessão) em algum banco de dados e usar um tokem para recuperá-la.

Tenho um pequeno handler para isso que criei a partir de uma dúvida sem resposta aqui no [stackoverflow](https://github.com/subversivo58/mdbsh) embora seja para `MongoDB` é facil seguir a lógica e adaptá-lo para `MySQL`.

Comment: Era o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!